# Sending a message to the mail

Tags: angular

I want to implement the "Support" function for my application. An input form will be used where users will enter a name, mail, and their message. After that, the sent message should come to my mail.

How can this be implemented? Or through what?

Comment: please write the tech you are using, or do you just want a pseudo explanation of the process?

Comment: @mnemosdev I wanted to know what is better to use for this? And is it possible to implement this without a server, i.e. e.g. Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems that you could implement the solution in two different ways.

1 - Use a public API or paid API service for e-mail, like the following (https://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-api/). I am not associated with the brand, this is just an example, you can find many other services with a search.

2 - Implement a nodejs solution on your own, with a call to an endpoint. This can be implemented with a package like this https://nodemailer.com/about/

Both approaches require you to write AJAX requests on the front-end of your application.